# Few questions when it comes to building an e-commerce website in Laravel and vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a few questions regarding building an e-commerce website. I want to program a small e-commerce website using Laravel and Vue. I know the basics of Laravel and Vue, but I'm struggling when it comes to selecting the best plan to program the website. So I have a few questions regarding that.

1. **Should an e-commerce website be dynamic or SPA?**
2. **Should I use a Vue router or built-in Laravel router?**
3. **Is it good practice to mix Vue components and Blade Template or should I separate Vue and Laravel when  it comes to the frontend?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Suggest you use nuxt universal, cuz need seo, spa didnt index well in search engine
2. For client side use Vue router, for rest api use laravel router
3. If you use vue + nuxt dont need blade

Comment: Should Nuxt be integrated with Laravel project or should I separate Laravel and Nuxt in different folders?

Comment: They are separate however you can put nuxt project in subfolder (example `client`) in you laravel project

Comment: Also there is laravel-nuxt package help you integrate nuxt with laravel, i personally dont use it  https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-nuxt